# Using the Fredholm Alternative to Prove that a Transformation is a Bijection

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $I$ be an interval in $\mathbb{R}.$

For $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $g_k, h_k \in L^2 (I)$ where
$$\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \left\Vert g_k \right\Vert_2^2 < \infty \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \left\Vert h_k \right\Vert_2^2$$

and 
$$\left\Vert g \right \Vert_2 = \bigg [\int_{I} \left|g(t)\right| ^2 dt \bigg ]^{\frac {1}{2}}$$.

Define $K : I \times I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$$K(x,y) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} g_n(x)h_n(y)$$
and $T : L^2(I) \rightarrow L^2(I)$ by
$$Tf(x) = \int_I K(x,y)f(y)dy.$$

Suppose that there exists $C \in (0, \infty)$ such that
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left| \langle f,h_n \rangle \right| ^2 \ge C\left\Vert f \right\Vert ^2 \quad (\forall f \in L^2 (I))$$
    and
    $$\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \left| \langle g_k, h_j \rangle \right|^2 < 1.$$
    Show that $I - T : L^2(I) \rightarrow L^2 (I)$ is bijective. Hint: By the Fredholm Alternative, it suffices to show that $\mathcal{N}(I - T) = \{0 \}$.

I know that when the nullity is zero, then it is injective. By the Fredholm alternative, then it is injective if and only if it is surjective, thus, $I−T$ is bijective. I guess the help I need is by showing that $\mathcal{N}(I−T)=\{0\}.$

Comment: I haven't thought about a complete answer, but here's what I would try first: If $\mathcal{N}(1-T)\neq 0$ then $T$ has a nonzero fixed point $f$ satisfying $\|f\|=1$.  Thus, $1=|(f,Tf)|=\left|\int_I\int_IK(x,y)f(x)f(y)\;dy\;dx\right|$ $=\left|\int_I\int_I\sum g_n(x)h_n(y)f(x)f(y)\;dy\;dx\right|$ $=\left|\sum\int_I g_n(x)f(x)\int_Ih_n(y)f(y)\;dy\;dx\right|$ $=\left|\sum (g_n,f)(h_n,f)\right|$ Now, can we find any inequalities to generate a contradiction from this?